# malloc error in iOS plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, unity-game-engine

I am getting a malloc error:

> "pointer being free was not allocated"

I am attempting to build a simple test iOS plugin for Unity.

The H file is just declarations and the M file is:

```
const char* _getDayAsString(int day)
{
    return [[DotWPlugin getDayAsString:day] UTF8String];
}

@implementation DotWPlugin

+ (NSString*)getDayAsString:(int)day
{
    if(day == 0)
        return @"Sunday";
    else if(day == 1)
        return @"Monday";
    else if(day == 2)
        return @"Tuesday";
    else if(day == 3)
        return @"Wednesday";
    else if(day == 4)
        return @"Thursday";
    else if(day == 5)
        return @"Friday";
    else if(day == 6)
        return @"Saturday";
    else
        return @"Invalid";
}

@end
```

It appears that the issue is that I am trying to turn an NSString* into a const char* and it doesn't like that.

Comment: Not quite. It seems that you are trying to `free()` the returned `const char *` pointer. Don't do that. (Oh, and BTW, that long chained `if` is horrible, use an array instead. And don't call your method `getDayAsString:`, the `get` prefix is reserved for something totally different in Cocoa.)

Comment: ought to be a switch() not if/elseif

Comment: The code itself, the include the IF statement, is largely irrelevant. I just wanted to ensure that I had the correct IF syntax as I've never used obc before. Once I figure out this issue, I will be replacing it with real code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`NSString` reference, `UTF8String` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBHCCED):

> The returned C string is a pointer to a structure **inside the string object**, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and **will certainly not have a longer lifetime**. Therefore, **you should copy the C string** if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you called this method.

In your case, `NSString` returned by the `getDayAsString:` method is released upon exit from the `_getDayAsString()` function. That is, `char*` returned by the `UTF8String` method is also freed.

In your `_getDayAsString()`, please create a copy of a null-terminated string returned by the `UTF8String` method and return that copy.

Comment: I tried: const char* str = [[DotWPlugin getDayAsString:day] UTF8String]; and then returning that, but it didn't work. I realize that I need to allocate memory for the pointer, but I don't remember how to do that. C# has made me soft in the head.

Comment: Thank you. I used the malloc method to create a new char*. If there is a better way, please let me know, but for now the problem is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was working with iOS 8 with Unity and encountered this issue. Cheers! +1